# Avoiding SVN Checkout and Update with Copy and Paste?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have about 20GB of files on a SVN on Assembla that I'd like copy on to another laptop that I have locally. I already have a local copy of the files on the SVN.

What I'd like to do is to copy and paste the files that I want from my existing computers drive to an external drive and to the new machine. Is this possible? Will this mess up the SVN connections?

I'm trying to avoid a 20GB "checkout" (SVN update).

Will this work?

Thanks!

Comment: This should work. Make sure you copy everything - including hidden files/folders.

Comment: Could you add the version information of your client? Especially 1.6.x or 1.7.x makes a difference.

Comment: I have version 1.6 SVN files on the old machine, and a TortoiseSVN that's compatible with 1.7 on the new machine. Please advise. @ Malenkiy_Scot - I've tried this....it hasn't worked out as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'svn export' command on the working copy.  That is, something like 'svn export c:/workingcopies/myproject c:/notworkingcopies/myproject'.  That will export the head revision of the working copy into the new directory.

I believe (but am not sure) that TortoiseSVN's export command will work the same way.

Newer versions of subversion store the original 'pristine' copy of the file in the .svn directory, use an sqlite database for stuff, and generally don't support simply copying the files like the older versions did.

I'm not sure when that format change occurred, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, however, whilst I',m aware that I can "export" the data - how do I then get "updates" (SVN updates) and commit changes. Is there such thing as an SVN Import?